# IIS 6 Server AppPool Recycling

Tags: iis, logging, iis-6

I am trying to turn the logs on for IIS 6, because I want to know if my workers are recycling too fast due to an error. Our application keeps getting a reset connection when running a ton of queries from our app.

How do I get more info on logs and stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris - I'm working on a similar problem as I'm writing some code to recycle app pools in both IIS6 and IIS7+. Just came across this article. Hope it helps.

[How to Configure Application Pool Recycle Event Logging in IIS 6.0](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=17)

This command, from that article, worked like a charm:

c:\cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/LogEventOnRecycle 255